# Upper bound for second derivative of cubic Hermite spline

Tags: upper-lower-bounds, interpolation, spline

My professor mentioned the following Theorem (which we didn't prove):

> Let $f \in C^4([a,b])$ and $s$ be the cubic Hermite spline interpolating $f$. Then
> $$
> \lVert s''\rVert_\infty \leq 3 \lVert f''\rVert_\infty.
> $$

Do you know where this theorem is proved or do you know how to prove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. A prove is described in

> de Boor, Carl: *A Practical Guide to Splines*, revised Edition (2001), Chapter III Theorem (12), p. 34.

Although formulated for linear splines.